# how to center label with placeholder?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I make a simple app of form .I am able to make almost 90% .But I have one issue .In my app I have label and in front of that i have text field .I need the label text should be centre or in same base as placeholder ,[image]

.I try to give **top:5px** **margin-top:5px** but nothing work .In other words 
Requirement label should be in same level as placeholder of textfield .

here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGPvge

```
.wrapper{
    padding-top:3em;
}
.label_title div {
    text-align: center;

    margin-top: 1em;
    position: relative;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ***`line-height: 50px;`*** to the DIV

```
.label_title div {
    line-height:50px; // <- Pull the text down 50px
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes in

```
.label_title div {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em; <<<---Remove this
    line-height: 50px; <<<---Add this
    position: relative;
}
```

Label will be align with place holder.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3r59gdq4/)